# Java 8 - How to set an object in a list from an object in another list?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to understand how can I copy/assign an object from a list to another list ?

For example : **ClassA** has an object of class **Sample** and **ClassB** also has an object of class **Sample** (other data members are different in both the classes as you can see in the example below).

I have lists of **ClassA** and **ClassB**.

Now if I want to set the object of class **Sample** in each element of **List< ClassB >** with the value of the **Sample** object from **List< ClassA >**, how can I do this using **Functional Style** in Java ?

I have shown how it can be done by **Imperative Style** but I really want to use **streams** here.

---

**Assumption :** sizes of **List< ClassA >** and **List< ClassB >** are equal

---

These are my classes:

Sample:

```
class Sample {
    int a;
    String str;

    public Sample() {}

    public Sample(int a, String str) {
        this.a = a;
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sample [a=" + a + ", str=" + str + "]";
    }
}
```

ClassA:

```
class ClassA {
    String someString;
    Sample sample;

    public ClassA(String someString, Sample sample) {
        this.someString = someString;
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassA [someString=" + someString + ", sample=" + sample + "]";
    }
}
```

ClassB:

```
class ClassB {
    int someNumber;
    int someOtherNumber;
    String someString;
    Sample sample;

    public ClassB(int someNumber, int someOtherNumber, String someString, Sample sample) {
        super();
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
        this.someOtherNumber = someOtherNumber;
        this.someString = someString;
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassB [someNumber=" + someNumber + ", someOtherNumber=" + someOtherNumber + ", someString="
                + someString + ", sample=" + sample + "]";
    }
}
```

And finally the main class:

```
public class ClassC {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ClassA a1 = new ClassA("abc", new Sample(1, "abc"));
        ClassA a2 = new ClassA("def", new Sample(2, "abcde"));
        ClassA a3 = new ClassA("pqr", new Sample(3, "abcdf"));
        List<ClassA> listOfA = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfA.add(a1);
        listOfA.add(a2);
        listOfA.add(a3);
        System.out.println(listOfA);

        ClassB b1 = new ClassB(100, 200, "zmr", null);
        ClassB b2 = new ClassB(101, 201, "tpu", null);
        ClassB b3 = new ClassB(103, 203, "zzz", null);
        List<ClassB> listOfB = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfB.add(b1);
        listOfB.add(b2);
        listOfB.add(b3);
        System.out.println("before : " + listOfB);

        // how to do this using stream ?
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfB.size(); i++) {
            listOfB.get(i).sample = listOfA.get(i).sample;
        }

        System.out.println("after : " + listOfB);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[ClassA [someString=abc, sample=Sample [a=1, str=abc]], ClassA [someString=def, sample=Sample [a=2, str=abcde]], ClassA [someString=pqr, sample=Sample [a=3, str=abcdf]]]

before : [ClassB [someNumber=100, someOtherNumber=200, someString=zmr, sample=null], ClassB [someNumber=101, someOtherNumber=201, someString=tpu, sample=null], ClassB [someNumber=103, someOtherNumber=203, someString=zzz, sample=null]]

after : [ClassB [someNumber=100, someOtherNumber=200, someString=zmr, sample=Sample [a=1, str=abc]], ClassB [someNumber=101, someOtherNumber=201, someString=tpu, sample=Sample [a=2, str=abcde]], ClassB [someNumber=103, someOtherNumber=203, someString=zzz, sample=Sample [a=3, str=abcdf]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) in functional way but honestly both are same

```
IntStream.range(0, listOfB.size())
         .forEach(i -> listOfB.get(i).sample = listOfA.get(i).sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using an AtomicInteger (so we can make it final) to loop through listB

```
   final AtomicInteger i= new AtomicInteger();
   listOfA.forEach( a-> listOfB.get(i.getAndIncrement()).sample = a.sample );
```

or the Iterator way

```
   Iterator<ClassB> iter = listOfB.iterator(); 
   listOfA.forEach( a-> iter.next().sample = a.sample );
```